# Get distinct row on the max column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a row of the table on the max column value

```
SELECT  MAX(PromoFileVersion) AS PromoFileVersion
        , FYearWeek
        , WeekPriority
        , PromoEventId  
FROM PromoCalendar   
GROUP BY FYearWeek, WeekPriority, PromoEventId
```

But I am getting duplicate records

[image]

Any help?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FYearWeek, WeekPriority, PromoEventId ORDER BY PromoFileVersion)` in a subquery and use it for filtering in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: could you please help me i am little weak in partition

Comment: I'm not seeing any duplicate records. The lines you marked are different from each other.

Comment: I need highlighted one with lastest PromoFileVersion

Comment: How do you define "lastest PromoFileVersion" ? With PromoFileVersion number ?

Comment: just need highest value of PromoFileVersion record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select pc.*
from (select pc.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by FYearWeek, WeekPriority order by PromoFileVersion desc) as seq
      from PromoCalendar  pc
     ) pc
where pc.seq = 1;
```

If you have ties with `PromoFileVersion`  then you cas use `dense_rank()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PromoFileVersion, FYearWeek, WeekPriority, PromoEventId  
FROM PromoCalendar p
where PromoFileVersion = (select max(PromoFileVersion) PromoFileVersion
                          from PromoCalendar p1
                          where p1.FYearWeek = p.FYearWeek 
                          and p1.WeekPriority = p.WeekPriority
                          GROUP BY  FYearWeek, WeekPriority);
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07f07d4274ab424d7c85dca249570493)